# Add http or https based on certain condition

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-security

I'm working on web application that is built on Spring Framework and also uses spring security.

I want users of the application to opt whether they want to use the application in SSL or not. Which means whether the application runs in https:// or http:// is conditional based on the logged in user.

Any brilliant ideas how can I achieve this.

I'm Using Tomcat and SSL is already configured.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ChannelProcessingFilter and the classes that it uses (ChannelDecisionManagerImpl, SecureChannelProcessor, RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint).

By default it is set up to redirect based on URL.   It is first in the filter chain.

You would want to add a filter towards the end of the chain (after authentication has been done) that does the redirect.